# search a string in a file which is also present in another file in unix

Tags: shell

I am new to Unix and had below requirement to finish my task.

I have `file1.dat` which has data as shown below.

```
case1.txt
case2.txt
case3.txt
case4.txt
case5.txt
```

file1.dat has only file names

I have folder which has above files mentioned in file1.dat

```
./all_files
case1.txt
case2.txt
case3.txt
case4.txt
```

data in case1.txt, case2.txt, case3.txt:

```
step1
step2
step3
step4
```

Now, I have to take particular step say step2 from each file, which is also present in file1.dat

Note: step2 is not line no:2 always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
while read f; do
  [ -f "$f" ] && sed -n '/step2/p' "$f"
done < file1.dat
```

It will output the line(s) matching `step2` in each file listed in `file.dat`.

Comment: But the output has also showing the not matching files... error: `sed: Cannot open file case5.txt`, case5.txt is present in file1.dat but not present in ./all_files folder. Please help

Comment: I updated to check if file exists before applying the sed command.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read f; do
    test -f "$f" && grep -F 'step2' "$f"
done <file1.dat
```

The lines of `file1.dat` (containing filenames) are read one by one into the `f` variable.

The body of the `while`-loop tests to make sure the file `$f` exists before using `grep` to look for the text string `step2` in the given file.

A slightly more verbose (but equivalent) version of the loop:

```
while read f; do
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
        grep -F 'step2' "$f"
    fi
done <file1.dat
```

Depending on where you run this, you might have to modify the `grep` command slightly.  For example, if you run this in the folder just above the subfolder with all the files:

```
grep -F 'step2' "all_files/$f"
```

It wasn't entirely clear in the question, but easily adjustable if needs be.

Of course, you could just bypass the `file1.dat` altogether and say

```
grep -F 'step2' all_files/case?.txt
```

without looping at all.

**Edit**: with new requirements:

```
find ./all_files -type f -name "case?.txt" -print0 |
xargs -0 grep -l -F 'step2'
```

This will recursively search through all folders under the `all_files` folder, find the files matching `case?.txt`, and report which ones contains the wanted string.

You may want to change the pattern to be more strict, maybe to something like `case[1-5].txt`.

Comment: thank you.. could you please help if the command will also work recursively.. sub-folders in ./all_files/ and in the display the file name as well `case1.txt: step2`, `case2.txt: step2`

Comment: This changes the solution completely, but ok, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: thank you.. but when i ran the command i got error output.  `#find ./all_files -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l -F 'step2'`
`find: bad option -print0`
`find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list`
`xargs: illegal option -- 0`
`xargs: Usage: xargs: [-t] [-p] [-e[eofstr]] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr] [-i[replstr]] [-L #] [-l[#]] [-n # [-x]] [-s size] [cmd [args ...]]`

Comment: @user180946 You're on a system where `find` doesn't have `-print0` and `xargs` doesn't have `-0`.  Remove these. You've already picked another answer as solving your problem.  If you have further questions, ask a completely new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take `step 2` from each file in the `./all_files` directory, then your `files.dat` isn't needed unless you need to use it as an exercise. If your shell supports *brace expansion*:

```
grep "step2" all_files/case{1,5}.txt
```

or using `files.dat` you could change into the `all_files` directory and redirect the content as input to `grep`:

```
cd all_files
grep "step2" $(<../files.dat)
```